# CoffeeScript fails to run from copied directory

Tags: javascript, web-services, node.js, coffeescript, foreman

In one directory I have a CoffeeScript application that runs fine when I type "foreman start."

In another directory I copied everything from that directory and typed "foreman start" again. But it doesn't run. Instead I get this error.

```
20:44:39 web.1     | started with pid 90836
20:44:40 web.1     | 
20:44:40 web.1     | node.js:201
20:44:40 web.1     |         throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
20:44:40 web.1     |               ^
20:44:40 web.1     | Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/cypher/git/heroku/falling-lightning-4940/node_modules/.bin/package.json'
20:44:40 web.1     |     at Object.openSync (fs.js:230:18)
20:44:40 web.1     |     at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:120:15)
20:44:40 web.1     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/cypher/git/heroku/falling-lightning-4940/node_modules/.bin/nodemon:10:26)
20:44:40 web.1     |     at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
20:44:40 web.1     |     at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
20:44:40 web.1     |     at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
20:44:40 web.1     |     at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
20:44:40 web.1     |     at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
20:44:40 web.1     |     at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
20:44:40 web.1     | process terminated
20:44:40 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

I don't get it. The 2 directories should be exactly the same. How can this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this part shows us the problem:

```
/Users/cypher/git/heroku/falling-lightning-4940/node_modules/.bin/package.json
```

Most copying methods won't copy files/directories that being with a `.`.  It is likely that the `.bin` directory is missing in the copy.

Comment: So what can be done about this? Also, I thought these commands were being run on the server. But that is a path on my computer. Those commands are running on my computer?

Comment: If a path from your desktop is showing up when you run it on a server, it probably means you've hard-coded in a complete path somewhere.  I would suggest grepping your code for all or some portion of that path if you don't know where it might be.

Comment: I found out it's because there's a space in the directory. If there's no space then it can compile. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @javascriptninja I don't see a space in the path in the error.  Where is the space?  What are the environments of your computer and the server?